# file.delete() returning false even file is writable

Tags: java, eclipse, file, directory, fileutils

I'am trying to copy a file to a directory and then deleting it, but file.delete() keeps returning false

Here is my code:

```
for (File file : list) {
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, path);
                    file.setWritable(true);                         
                    System.out.println(file.delete());
                    if(file.exists()){
                        file.deleteOnExit();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note that you need to have the proper permissions in order for `file.setWritable(true);` to work. Likely your user don't have the rights to delete the file.

Comment: Then, what can I do?

Comment: Execute the program with a user that has the rights to delete the file

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) says you should try to use `Files.delete` to diagnose the problem because that method throws exception on error.

Comment: Did your copy routine close the file?  Windows will not allow you to delete an open file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ideas that you can work it out.

- If you want to delete file first close all the connections and streams. after that delete the file
- Make sure you have the delete permissions for the file
- Make sure you are in right directory. Try using absolute path for deleting the file, in case delete is not working. Path might not be correct for the file.
- Use Files.delete. The delete(Path) method deletes the file or throws an exception if the deletion fails. For example, if the file does not exist a NoSuchFileException is thrown. You can catch the exception to determine why the delete failed as follows: See  Oracle docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html)

  ```
  try {
      Files.delete(path);
  } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
      System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
  } catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
      System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
  } catch (IOException x) {
      // File permission problems are caught here.
      System.err.println(x);
  }
  ```